# Event handler executing but not showing effect

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dom-events

I'm working on a Javascript-based painting application, where I'm now making a menu, as if the client area was a desktop window.

[image: The menu with a dropdown active]

In this menu of course, I have some main tabs, their dropdowns with all the items and sometimes subtabs leading to child dropdowns. For my question, let's focus on the main tabs (like 'File' or 'Edit'). The problem, in short form, is that they don't react by showing their dropdowns.

In the process of initializing the page, I grab all the elements by class:

```
MTabs = menubar.getElementsByClassName('mainTab');
```

I then add the event handlers. The function that I pass into addEventListener() is returned by an intermediary function that assembles the specific function with the node reference to the node that the handler is for. I found an [example](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) ("The infamous loop problem"->"Working reference") that showed this type of dealing with adding event handlers from within a loop. These are the calls to `addEventListener(`):

```
for (var i=0, n=MTabs.length; i<n; i++){ // MTab
    node = MTabs[i];
    node.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver_MTabs(node));
    node.addEventListener('click', onClick_MTabs(node));
}
```

These are the functions that return the handler functions:

```
var onMouseOver_MTabs = function(node){
    var dropdown = getChildDropdown(node);
    return function(){
        if (menuClicked){
            deactivateMenu(); // Hide all dropdowns
            setActive(node); // add active class to this tab
            setActive(dropdown); // show this tabs dropdown
        }
    }
}

var onClick_MTabs = function(node){
    var dropdown = getChildDropdown(node);
    return function(){
        if (menuClicked){
            quitMenu(); // Hide all menu elements, set menuClicked false
        }
        else {
            setActive(node);
            setActive(dropdown);
            openMenu(); // set menuClicked true
        }
    }
}
```

The global boolean variable `menuClicked` tells whether the user has clicked on the menu. If true, elements of the menu should react to a mouseover event, and display the correct dropdown(s). When a tab is clicked (in the image above the 'tools' tab), this variable is set to true within `openMenu()`. The strange thing is that after the function has returned, the variable is false again. I noticed this by `console.log()` tracing. Also, the dropdown is not shown. I expected this to work (it has before), as the code is very simple:

```
var setActive = function(node){
// Adding css class that sets visibility:visible for dropdowns
    node.classList.add('menuActive');
}
```

To me, this looks like the handlers are not setting the actual, global `menuClicked` variable, but why would they not? Or do the functions return the handlers with `menuClicked` hard-coded as false into their if statements?

I've tried many things, still I'm wondering why this doesn't work out. I guess I've lost myself a little in the demanding freedoms of JavaScript ... :)

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/01byxr2k/1/)

Comment: Can you add the html for the menu, so it is easier for us to reproduce or analyse what is going on? Or if you can create a working code snippet showing the problem, even better

Comment: Where are you setting your `menuClicked` as `true` ? Also what is `deactivateMenu()` ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh menuClicked is set true by openMenu() and false by quitMenu(). deactivateMenu() hides all menu elements, it is also called inside quitMenu().

Comment: @Sam just what kind of dom elements are these tabs... ? `div`, `li` or what ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh they are `span`.

Comment: I can not figure out the problem in your code... May be you yourself can figure out what exactly is happening by adding detailed logs like `console.log("onClick_MTabls :: itself :: start :: node : " + node.id )` and `console.log("onClick_MTabls :: return function :: start :: node : " + node.id )`

Comment: Or you can even use `bunyan.js` if you are using `browserify`

Comment: You mean adding trace statements? Well my code is really simple actually, how could it fail? `menuClicked` is surely not out of scope, the handlers do execute. May it be something other than the code? I'll try tracing though ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70513/discussion-between-sam-and-sarvesh-kumar-singh).

Comment: @Sam I can not... Chat requires real time communication... too many things to do today... but others in Chat-room will certainly help you.

Comment: `menuClicked` is a global variable. I don't know what other code you've got running, if any. If something else happens to be using the same global variable it will cause problems. You could try either (0) renaming it to something more obscure, or (1) enclosing the whole script inside `(function() { var menuClicked; ... })();` to protect its scope (assuming it's not split into separate files or `<script>` tags).

Comment: The content of the JSFiddle is all code belonging to the page. I have the html file, the css file separately ("master.css"), and two separate javascript files (first being all until addEventListener for window.onmousemove ("main.js"), second all after it ("menu.js")).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/ssantee/9gaj49be/1/

The factory thing you are doing while adding the event handlers is not acting as I think you would expect. The functions are executing as you assign the handlers, leading to several executions prior any interaction with the page. I would refactor that to find the event target during event handling. Much more straight-forward.

So, rather than

```
node.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver_STabs(node));
```

Do this to assign the handlers.

```
node.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver_STabs);
```

Then, the handlers should take the single argument 'event', and use it to find the target of the event

```
var node = event.target;
```

As for the menuClicked var, I think this is working as you expect however another factor is making it unpredictable; the click event is propagating from the tab to 'menu_background', leading to 'quitMenu' being called immediately after 'openMenu'.

Adding

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

in your event handlers will prevent this, as I have done in my fork of your fiddle. Please see 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation
for a more in-depth explanation.

Also, importantly, I don't think you can attach a handler to window load with addEventListener. There are a few approaches you could take to initializing your globals but I would remove

```
//doesn't work
window.addEventListener('load',initMain);
```

and move your initialization code to another script tag, just before the html

```
</body>
```

tag. Alternately, move the entire script there and move the initialization code to the bottom of it all. This is not well reflected in my fiddle because it's all in a single box and I think jsfiddle wraps a window.onload around all of it.

Comment: Wow, that all makes sense once I see it. I had no idea what was breaking my script and this was a project that I have once already abandoned months ago. Thanks (from a hobbyist) for your all-around answer!

Answer (score 0):

Did a jsfiddle with CSS only menu and a way for you to detect the clicked action. Maybe this example helps a bit to build upon that approach.

https://jsfiddle.net/tanertopal/pnamnmc3/1/

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <span>File</span>
        <ul>
            <li action="open">Open</li>
            <li action="save">Save</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Edit</span>
        <ul>
            <li action="copy">Copy</li>
            <li action="paste">Paste</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
* {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue";
    font-size: 14px;
}
body {
    background: grey;
}

ul {
    height: 16px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    color: white;
}

ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

ul.menu li:hover ul, ul.menu li ul:hover {
    display: block;
}

ul.menu li > ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 34px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

ul.menu li > ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

ul.menu li > span {
    padding: 5px 0;
}

ul.menu li.show > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
var menu = document.querySelectorAll('ul.menu')[0];

menu.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var target = event.target;
    var action = target.getAttribute("action");

    // now do something with action
    alert(action);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example, it seems a lot "cleaner" to me. Though, I'm not yet a CSS pro and your approach doesn't tell me why my own approach with Javascript is not working, which my question is all about ... I may consider using your way of doing it after taking a little CSS self-schooling, but I'd like to know what's wrong with my Javascript.